# On Linux QDir::entrylist() not returning all files and directories for /dev

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I know the /dev device files aren't regular files but didn't notice anything
in the documentation about that being an issue.

My code simply creates a QDir for /dev and uses the QDir::entrylist() method
to display the list of files and directories. It appears to be only printing
directories under /dev but no device files.

Comment: Have you tried setting the [filters](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdir.html#Filter-enum)?

Comment: I just realized Dir::system filter causes the entrylist() to print system files (i.e., sda1 ...) and so on.

Comment: @G.M. If you answer. I'll accept your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dir::system filter causes the QDir::entrylist() to print system files (i.e., sda1 ...) and so on.